# Apache htaccess rule supresses bandwidth

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

If rule below(.htaccess) is applies to the folder and as soons a im logged into appliation and try to open simple video from url. Then video is very poorly buffered whatever the browser may be.
My best guess is that every video buffer request tries to authenticate.
Can it may be the case?

```
Options -Indexes
<IfModule rewrite_module>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\/content\/lessons\/.*$
    RewriteRule !^((.*.php)|(.*\/))$ %1/view_file.php?server=1
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Not enough information to help you. Give us an example of url for your video. Without any context, I'm only able to tell you what the rule is doing/matching

Comment: I cant give you url cause security reasons. But i can give you the view_file.php content (https://www.dropbox.com/s/9kxmgxhgp7wi8as/view_file.php?dl=0)

I can describe the problem.

It seems all video buffering gous through view_file.php

Comment: I'm not asking for the entire url, you can remove your domain name if you want. For instance, if your url is `http://example.com/a/b/c/video` then I only need `/a/b/c/video`. Without it, I can't help you and I won't be able to find the problem

Comment: /www/content/lessons/25/2018-04-24_Protecting_Personal_Data_and_GDPR_Veiwpoint_of_Cyber_Security.mp4

Comment: This url will be rewritten to `/www/view_file.php?server=1`. So, indeed, it goes through `view_file.php`. Is it intended or would you want to avoid it ?

Comment: It is inteded, is it possible to avoid that after user authorization is made?

Comment: Maybe, that depends on what authorization you're using. Could you describe it ?

Comment: It uses software in auth(php & session)

Comment: The easiest would be to directly handle that check inside `view_file.php` itself. After the rewrite, you can check that `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is `/www/content/lessons/xxxxxx` and, if so, serve the file. That would allow you to easily check if authentication is done or not